# List comprehension with tuples

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

```py
list_of_tuples = [(2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2)]

def my_function(list_of_tuples):
  best = list_of_tuples[0]
    for r in list_of_tuples:
        if r[0] * r[1] > best[0] * best[1]:
            best = r
    return best
```

I want to write the above function in one line and this is my result

```py
return [i for i in rectangles if i[0] * i[1] > list_of_tuples[0][0] * list_of_tuples[0][1]]
```

The problem is that I don't know how to write that part with `best = r`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Python can help you with this:

```
def my_function(list_of_tuples):
    return max(list_of_tuples, key=lambda k: k[0]*k[1])
```

Comment: that is a clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `operator.mul()` and `functools.reduce()` to get the product of every element in each tuple, and then you can take the tuple with the maximum product using `max()`.

[Tim Roberts's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72049506/17769815) answer is good for when you only have tuples of size two, but this approach can be used for tuples of arbitrary length (the number of elements in each tuple doesn't even have to be the same!):

```py
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

max(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: reduce(mul, x))
```

Even simpler, you can do:

```py
from math import prod

max(list_of_tuples, key=prod)
```

by a suggestion from [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy).

These output:

```py
(3, 3)
```

Comment: thank you!for what i tried there is no chance to introduce the part with best = r in my code ?

Comment: You might be able to produce something similar using the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) (Python 3.8+ only), but in general, you shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects like what you're describing.

Comment: Right.  List comprehensions should not be maintaining state.  That kind of violates the functional principles on which they are based.

Comment: Why not `math.prod`?

Comment: (`math.prod` is still relatively new [3.8]; it isn't top of mind for a lot of developers.)